# How do I prevent Live Agent from automatically opening subtabs in service console

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console

We're going through Live Agent and Service Console deployment and when a chat request is received it automatically opens subtabs to the transcript in service console for lead, contact, account, and case. Our reps want to manually open or associate the transcript with one of those on close without having to close tabs for all the opened ones. Anyone know how to prevent them from auto opening?

Answer (score 2):

You can control which tabs open when a chat arrives within your Console settings. In the Setup tree go to Create->Apps and edit the console you're using. There's a section called 'Choose Chat Workspace Options' where you can add or remove these tabs.

[image]

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/live_agent_administrator.pdf

Comment: Thanks so much Paul. It looks like when I do that though I don't then have the option to manually lookup and attach to records from those objects after closing the chat. And unlike current experience where it opens them but closing the parent tab and not saving changes at the end closing everything without creating a case, if I remove the related tabs here it actually automatically creates the case and saves it even when I exit. A happy medium would be great but at least I know the option. Thanks again!